# how to deploy Spring Cloud war to old container

Tags: spring, deployment, cloud, war

I had a Spring Cloud project which was deployed in embeded tomcat. Now I modify the project add web.xml and make the Application class extends SpringBootServletInitializer. I followed the instruction of 81.5 Deploying a WAR in an Old (Servlet 2.5) Container in below link. But I found that the application.properties was not loaded. And the server port listed in application.properties was not listened.

[http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-servlet-2-5]
Deploying a WAR in an Old (Servlet 2.5) Container

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=api-gateway
server.port=5555

# routes to serviceId
zuul.routes.api-a.path=/api-a/**
zuul.routes.api-a.serviceId=service-A

zuul.routes.api-b.path=/api-b/**
zuul.routes.api-b.serviceId=service-B

# routes to url
zuul.routes.api-a-url.path=/api-a-url/**
zuul.routes.api-a-url.url=http://localhost:2222/

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:9999/eureka/
```